# Cross Referencing MASTER Table with SUB TABLES in ORACLE SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, unique, cross-reference

I farly new to Oracle SQL Developer and I have an idea that I would like to attempt, but I am not sure how it might be possible (and this just might be a silly question anyways)

Here are the facts of the case:

- I have a schema in oracle that contains a number of tables. Around 100 or so.
- Within those 100 tables about 20 of them are what we call 'EVENT TABLES' which log various types of EVENTS that happen on the database. Each EVENT is unique.
- 19 tables are sub category EVENT tables. Bascially, tables that are categorized by type. (i.e. an event table for changes in CLIENT CONTACT INFORMATION, another event table for changes in LAND OWNERSHIP, another event table for PAYMENT INFORMATION, etc)
- There is one EVENT table that is the MASTER TABLE, which contains ALL events, regardless of type. This table is loaded with events from the 19 sub category tables. If an event is logged into one particular sub table, it is logged in the MASTER TABLE as well
- All tables have a column named 'EVENT_NUMBER_ID' which is a unique number logged against the event that took place. This column is the join column between the 19 sub category tables and the master table

I want to build a query that cross references an EVENT NUMBER from the master table to it's particular sub table. For example, someone gives me an event number. I can go to the EVENT MASTER TABLE and find it there, but I'd also like to find out which sub table it resides in.

Comment: What would you want this query to return, exactly?  Just the name of the subcategory table that the event is in?  The data from that subcategory table?  Something else?  You can do this by outer joining to all 19 subcategory tables and then figuring out which one of the joins returns data.  That may not, however, be a terribly efficient thing to do constantly...

Comment: I think at this point, I'd just be happy knowing which sub category table the event number is from. I already know it's in the master table, but with the volume of records (2 million or so) It's not easy.  I also figure there's a better way to find out which sub category table an even number sits in, without having to query each table individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to determine which subcategory table an `event` relates to in a single query, you'd need to join the `event` table to each of the subcategory tables.  That may not be the most efficient query to run constantly, however

```
SELECT e.event_number_id,
       (case when sc1.event_number_id IS NOT NULL then 'SC1'
             when sc2.event_number_id IS NOT NULL then 'SC2'
             ...
             when sc19.event_number_id IS NOT NULL then 'SC19'
         end)
  FROM event e
       LEFT OUTER JOIN subcategory1 sc1
         ON( e.event_number_id = sc1.event_number_id )
       LEFT OUTER JOIN subcategory2 sc2
         ON( e.event_number_id = sc2.event_number_id )
       ... 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN subcategory19 sc19
         ON( e.event_number_id = sc19.event_number_id )
 WHERE e.event_number_id = xxx
```

From a table design perspective, if you're going to have subcategory tables, you'd normally store the subcategory in the `event` table in order to tell you which table to join to rather than trying to infer that information later.  You could potentially add that column now, use the query I posted to backfill the information, and then populate that column going forward.

Rather than joining to 19 tables, if you're really just doing a single-row lookup, it may be more efficient to write a PL/SQL function that checks the tables in the order of likelihood (i.e. if one event subcategory constitutes 20% of all events, check that table first) and stops looking once it finds the match.

Comment: Hey Justin. I wasn't looking for anything overly complicated at this point and this solution provided the answer I was looking for. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 1):

Justin's way will work fine.  If the event number is indexed in all columns I'd suggest the following:

Create a view like the following

```
     Select 'Type1' as EventType, event_number_id from event1
       union all
     Select 'Type2' as EventType, event_number_id from event2
       union all
     Select 'Type3' as EventType, event_number_id from event3
       union all
     Select 'Type4' as EventType, event_number_id from event4
       union all
         -- ...
     Select 'TypeN' as EventType, event_number_id from eventN
```

(you can add more columns if they make sense)

Now all you need to do is query this view for a given event number.  If event number is indexed on all tables it will be super fast.

Comment: Hey Hogan, I got to working on Justin's answer and it worked for me. I like your union idea.  Something I might look into when I ahve more time to refine some things on my queries. Cheers.